# Crossing Dateline with cartopy.io.img_tiles

Tags: python, cartopy

I'm trying to figure out how to generate a map that crosses the dateline with Cartopy and a terrain from img_tiles.  Here is what I have so far:

```
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.feature as cfeature
import cartopy.io.img_tiles as cimgt
import shapely.geometry as sgeom

my_dpi = 96
plt.figure(figsize=(1530/my_dpi, 900/my_dpi), dpi=my_dpi, frameon=False)
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.0, right=1.0, top=1.0, bottom=0)
ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.Mercator(central_longitude=180))
terrain = cimgt.Stamen('terrain-background')
ax.add_image(terrain, 4)     
states = cfeature.NaturalEarthFeature('cultural', 'admin_1_states_provinces', '10m', edgecolor='darkblue',facecolor='none')
ax.add_feature(states, linewidth = 0.1, linestyle='-')

# draw box
box = sgeom.box(minx=69, maxx=210, miny=-57, maxy=13.5)
ax.add_geometries([box], ccrs.PlateCarree(), facecolor='coral', 
                   edgecolor='black', alpha=0.5)
# Set extent
ax.set_extent(oceania_coords,  crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())

plt.show()
```

When I draw a box around the region I want to zoom in on, it looks correct.

[image]

When I try to ax.set_extent on this range, it seems to set all of the cfeatures correctly but screws up with the img_tiles features.

[image]

Is there any way to work around this?  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution that is good enough for me, by abutting two subplots with the appropriate ratios and borders turned off.  There is a tiny artifact on the seam, but I'm mostly slicing ocean in this frame so I'm ok with it. When I have Russia in the frame, it's more obvious.

```
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.feature as cfeature
import cartopy.io.img_tiles as cimgt
import shapely.geometry as sgeom
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
my_dpi=96
f = plt.figure(figsize=(1530/my_dpi, 900/my_dpi), dpi=my_dpi, frameon=False)
spec = gridspec.GridSpec(ncols=2, nrows=1,width_ratios=[111,30])
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.0, right=1.0, top=1.0, bottom=0)

ax1 = f.add_subplot(spec[0],projection=ccrs.Mercator(central_longitude=180))
terrain = cimgt.Stamen('terrain-background')
ax1.add_image(terrain, 3)
states = cfeature.NaturalEarthFeature('cultural', 'admin_1_states_provinces', '10m', edgecolor='darkblue',facecolor='none')
ax1.add_feature(states, linewidth = 0.1, linestyle='-')
ax1.set_extent([69, 180, -57, 13.5],  crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())
plt.gca().outline_patch.set_visible(False)

ax2 = f.add_subplot(spec[1],projection=ccrs.Mercator(central_longitude=180))
ax2.add_image(terrain, 3)
ax2.add_feature(states, linewidth = 0.1, linestyle='-')
ax2.set_extent([-180,-150, -57, 13.5],  crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())
plt.gca().outline_patch.set_visible(False)

plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0)
```

[image]